# Can I simplify (solve) a certain DifferenceRoot expression?

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, recursion, difference-equations

I've generated this expression

```
DifferenceRoot[
  Function[{\[FormalY], \[FormalN]}, {62022240 + 
      545995032 \[FormalN] + 2056791388 \[FormalN]^2 + 
      4333244560 \[FormalN]^3 + 5587600700 \[FormalN]^4 + 
      4517982000 \[FormalN]^5 + 2238010000 \[FormalN]^6 + 
      621200000 \[FormalN]^7 + 
      74000000 \[FormalN]^8 + (-19027008 - 158454120 \[FormalN] - 
         566231672 \[FormalN]^2 - 1135130960 \[FormalN]^3 - 
         1397526400 \[FormalN]^4 - 1082880000 \[FormalN]^5 - 
         516080000 \[FormalN]^6 - 138400000 \[FormalN]^7 - 
         16000000 \[FormalN]^8) \[FormalY][\[FormalN]] + 
      3 (2 + 5 \[FormalN]) (3 + 5 \[FormalN])^2 (4 + 
         5 \[FormalN]) (6 + 5 \[FormalN]) (5 + 6 \[FormalN]) (7 + 
         6 \[FormalN]) (31 + 20 \[FormalN]) \[FormalY][
        1 + \[FormalN]] == 0, \[FormalY][1] == 158/31}]][n]
```

Can it be placed in a more transparent form and/or meaningfully manipulated?

Comment: What do you mean by "meaningfully manipulated"? They can be used within `Sum[]`, `Product[]`, and a number of other symbolic functions. If you want an explicit solution of the underlying difference equation, you could try feeding it to `RSolve[]`, or use `FunctionExpand[]` on the `DifferenceRoot[]` itself.

Comment: OK, thanks very much J. M.  I'm aware of Function Expand and, of course, FullSimplify. I tried applying RSolve--but I wasn't quite sure what to import to it, and got error messages. So what is the correct code for applying RSolve here?

Answer (score 2):

The OP in a comment above asks how to use `RSolve` on the problem.  `RSolve` can, in fact, be used to obtain an explicit expression for an arbitrary term in the series, although this expression is not particularly useful.  Designate the `DifferenceRoot` in the question as `f`.  Then,

```
First[Head[f]][y, n]
(* {62022240 + 545995032 n + 2056791388 n^2 + 4333244560 n^3 + 
    5587600700 n^4 + 4517982000 n^5 + 2238010000 n^6 + 621200000 n^7 + 
    74000000 n^8 + (-19027008 - 158454120 n - 566231672 n^2 - 
    1135130960 n^3 - 1397526400 n^4 - 1082880000 n^5 - 
    516080000 n^6 - 138400000 n^7 - 16000000 n^8) y[n] + 
    3 (2 + 5 n) (3 + 5 n)^2 (4 + 5 n) (6 + 5 n) (5 + 6 n) (7 + 6 n) 
    (31 + 20 n) y[1 + n] == 0, y[1] == 158/31} *)
```

gives the corresponding recurrence relation and initial condition, which can be solved after several minutes of computation by

```
(y /. RSolve[%, y, n][[1, 1]])
(* g = Function[{n}, (3^(-3 n) 64^(-2 + n) (3 + 5 n) ... *)
```

With a `LeafCount` of `25894`, it is far too long to reproduce here.

Not surprisingly, the `Difference Root` for `n -> 1` returns the initial condition in less than a second.

```
f /. n -> 1
(* 158/31 *)
```

It also returns results for larger `n` quickly.  For instance,

```
f /. n -> 3
(* 22801/3692 *)
```

In contrast, the `RSolve` result

```
FullSimplify[g[1]]
```

takes several minutes to return the same initial values and

```
FullSimplify[g[3]]
```

runs for an hour without producing a result.  Thus, as noted originally, `RSolve` indeed produces an explicit expression, but it is not useful in practice.

For completeness, `f` can be plotted over a wide range in several seconds.

```
ListLogLinearPlot[Table[f, {n, 1, 1000, 10}], PlotRange -> All, DataRange -> 1000]
```

[image]