# Find RSolve solution reflecting special structure of DifferenceRoot[Function[{\[FormalY], \[FormalN]}

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions, difference-equations

`RSolve` yields a large (multi-page) [solution (LeafCount=25891)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/123660/1063) containing a number of 7F6 (and higher) hypergeometric functions when applied to

```
DifferenceRoot[Function[{\[FormalY], \[FormalN]}, {62022240 + 545995032*\[FormalN] + 2056791388*\[FormalN]^2 + 
   4333244560*\[FormalN]^3 + 5587600700*\[FormalN]^4 + 4517982000*\[FormalN]^5 + 2238010000*\[FormalN]^6 + 
   621200000*\[FormalN]^7 + 74000000*\[FormalN]^8 + (-19027008 - 158454120*\[FormalN] - 566231672*\[FormalN]^2 - 
     1135130960*\[FormalN]^3 - 1397526400*\[FormalN]^4 - 1082880000*\[FormalN]^5 - 516080000*\[FormalN]^6 - 
     138400000*\[FormalN]^7 - 16000000*\[FormalN]^8)*\[FormalY][\[FormalN]] + 3*(2 + 5*\[FormalN])*(3 + 5*\[FormalN])^2*
    (4 + 5*\[FormalN])*(6 + 5*\[FormalN])*(5 + 6*\[FormalN])*(7 + 6*\[FormalN])*(31 + 20*\[FormalN])*\[FormalY][1 + \[FormalN]] == 0, 
 \[FormalY][1] == 158/31}]][n]
```

But I think that `RSolve` is working here without respect to the apparent 
highly-structured form of the input (just essentially expanding everything out before further proceeding). But various subject-matter considerations lead me to conjecture that there is a much more compact/elegant solution. (Of course, one can try to simplify the actual very large solution--but previous experience indicates that is a most formidable--if even doable--task.)

So, my question here is how--if at all possible--one might incorporate the special structure of the DifferenceRoot expression in the `RSolve` (or some equivalent) process?

Comment: Thanks J_Nat. Yes, that is precisely what I did--with the very large output (LeafCount=25891) being produced after (roughly) a few hours.

Comment: After about an hour `FunctionExpand` yields a result with a `LeafCount` of "only" 19429.  It contains instances of `HypergeometricPFQ` with 54 different arguments.

Comment: And, after an additional quarter-hour, `Simplify[%, n \[Element] Integers && n > 0] reduces `LeafCount` to 13886.

Comment: Thanks very much, bbgodfrey! I guess I could replicate your results, but maybe you could send them to me (slater@kitp.ucsb.edu). (I wasn't aware of the particular use of Simplify[]--interesting!)

Comment: Wow, I'm impressed and thankful for all your hard efforts, bbgodfey. I've been "messing around" for some time with big hypergeometric expressions strongly related, it would seem off-hand, to this one (see Fig. 3 in http://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.6617.pdf). Off-hand I'm not optimistic about the use of FullSimplify--but let's hope for something miraculous.

Comment: Also, my experience in the past with similar "humongous" hypergeometric-based expressions that Mathematica generates like the one under consideration, is that if one isolates those terms that do not depend upon the variable ("n" here) that they may reduce in toto miraculously to zero. This can be found by calculating the numerical value of the isolated terms to high precision.

Comment: I tried replacing the eight-degree polynomial beginning with 62022240 with f[FormalN] and applying RSolve. The result seemed quite promising, but then when I replaced f[FormalN] in the solution by the original eight-degree polynomial, the results seemed not correct. So, I don't offhand know what the conceptual problem here is. Also, I tried alternatively replacing the other two major terms by f[FormalN] and similarly proceeding. Now things seemed a little more problematical with two dummy variables (K[1] and K[2]) appearing, not one.

Answer (score 1):

As previously indicated, RSolve provides a large ("hypergeometric-function-abundant") solution (LeafCount=25981). Mathematica indicates that the solution naturally breaks into two parts--the first having a LeafCount of 5250. High-precision numerics, followed by rationalizations and use of the FindSequenceFunction command gives for this first part the relatively simple (hypergeometric-free) formula

```
(5*3^(-1 - 3*\[FormalN])*8^(1 + 2*\[FormalN])*(3 + 5*\[FormalN])*Pochhammer[7/10, \[FormalN]]*Pochhammer[9/10, \[FormalN]]*
Pochhammer[1, \[FormalN]]*Pochhammer[11/10, \[FormalN]]*Pochhammer[13/10, \[FormalN]]*
Pochhammer[3/2, \[FormalN]])/((11 + 20*\[FormalN])*Pochhammer[2/5, \[FormalN]]*Pochhammer[3/5, \[FormalN]]*
Pochhammer[4/5, \[FormalN]]*Pochhammer[5/6, \[FormalN]]*Pochhammer[7/6, \[FormalN]]*Pochhammer[6/5, \[FormalN]])
```

Now if we subtract its values from the original DifferenceRoot[Function, giving us the values of the second part, we, quite amazingly it would seem, get back exactly the original function but for the single change that y[1] now equals -4102/93, rather than 158/31 = 474/93. It would seem that this must be indicating something of a profound nature about the original function (and hopefully a relatively simple formula for it), but at present I don't see what that is.

Comment: RSolve has now given me the solution with y[1]=-4102/93, instead of the original 158/31 = 474/93. Again, the solution naturally breaks into two parts, with exactly the same LeafCounts. But now, the first part (which had the relatively simple hypergeometric-free formula for it previously with the use of 158/31) turns out to be identically zero (as high-precision numerics convincingly indicate). So, the other part would simply yield the values used to produce the second DifferentialRoot[Function to which RSolve was just applied.

Comment: On the mathematics stack exchange site, I inquired as to how Maple might handle the equation--and was given a solution, presently "hypergeometric-free", but with a (yet unperformed) summation that conceivably might lead to hypergeometric functions.  Here is the link   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1903720/what-solution-does-maple-give-to-this-difference-equation/1903999#1903999

Comment: I did translate the Maple output of Love to Mathematica and performed the (implicit) summation. The result has a very similar nature to the one originally obtained in Mathematica, with the same set of hypergeometric terms, all with argument 27/64, appearing. So, it would seem that the two languages take similar approaches (as to which I was curious) to the recurrence equations.