# To what extent can one simplify these products of gamma functions?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions, expression-manipulation, products

I have these three expressions

```
Gamma[1/2 + k]*Gamma[7/10 + k]*Gamma[9/10 + k]*Gamma[1 + k]^6*Gamma[11/10 + k]*
  Gamma[13/10 + k]*Gamma[3/2 + k]*Gamma[17/10 + k]*Gamma[19/10 + k]*Gamma[21/10 + k]*
  Gamma[23/10 + k]*Gamma[5/2 + k]*Gamma[13/5 + k]*Gamma[27/10 + k]*Gamma[29/10 + k]*
  Gamma[3 + k]*Gamma[31/10 + k]*Gamma[33/10 + k]*Gamma[7/2 + k]*Gamma[18/5 + k]*
  Gamma[37/10 + k]*Gamma[39/10 + k]*Gamma[41/10 + k]*Gamma[43/10 + k]*Gamma[9/2 + k]*
  Gamma[23/5 + k]*Gamma[47/10 + k]*Gamma[49/10 + k]*Gamma[51/10 + k]*Gamma[53/10 + k]*
  Gamma[28/5 + k]
```

and

```
Gamma[n]*Gamma[2/5 + n]^2*Gamma[3/5 + n]^3*Gamma[4/5 + n]^2*Gamma[5/6 + n]*
  Gamma[7/6 + n]*Gamma[6/5 + n]^2*Gamma[7/5 + n]*Gamma[8/5 + n]^2*Gamma[9/5 + n]*
  Gamma[11/6 + n]*Gamma[13/6 + n]*Gamma[11/5 + n]*Gamma[3 + 2*n]
```

and

```
Gamma[3/2 + k + n]*Gamma[17/10 + k + n]*Gamma[19/10 + k + n]*Gamma[2 + k + n]*
  Gamma[21/10 + k + n]*Gamma[23/10 + k + n]*Gamma[5/2 + k + n]*Gamma[13/5 + k + n]*
  Gamma[27/10 + k + n]*Gamma[29/10 + k + n]*Gamma[3 + k + n]*Gamma[31/10 + k + n]*
  Gamma[33/10 + k + n]*Gamma[18/5 + k + n]
```

Also, relatedly

```
 (1/10)*(23 + 10*n)*(1 + n)!*(2 + n)!*(1 + 2*n)!*(3 + 2*n)!*((1/10)*(7 + 10*n))!*
  ((1/10)*(9 + 10*n))!*((1/10)*(11 + 10*n))!*((1/10)*(13 + 10*n))!*((1/10)*(17 + 10*n))!*
  ((1/10)*(19 + 10*n))!*((1/10)*(21 + 10*n))!
```

To what extent can these be simplified?

Comment: I think the answer to your question is "Not much."  For example (assuming `n` and `k` are integers), `Gamma[2/5+n]^2 Gamma[7/5+n]` will simplify to `(2/5+n) Gamma[2/5+n]^3`.

Answer (score 4):

Simplification is many times in the eye of the beholder.  But assuming `k` and `n` are non-negative integers, use of the following rule might help somewhat (but likely not very much):

```
rule = {Gamma[x_] /; x > 1 -> (x - 1) Gamma[x - 1], 
   Gamma[x_ + z__] /; x > 1 -> (x + z - 1) Gamma[x - 1 + z]};
```

Here is that rule applied to your first example:

```
Gamma[1/2 + k]*Gamma[7/10 + k]*Gamma[9/10 + k]*Gamma[1 + k]^6*
  Gamma[11/10 + k]*Gamma[13/10 + k]*Gamma[3/2 + k]*Gamma[17/10 + k]*
  Gamma[19/10 + k]*Gamma[21/10 + k]*Gamma[23/10 + k]*Gamma[5/2 + k]*
  Gamma[13/5 + k]*Gamma[27/10 + k]*Gamma[29/10 + k]*Gamma[3 + k]*
  Gamma[31/10 + k]*Gamma[33/10 + k]*Gamma[7/2 + k]*Gamma[18/5 + k]*
  Gamma[37/10 + k]*Gamma[39/10 + k]*Gamma[41/10 + k]*Gamma[43/10 + k]*
  Gamma[9/2 + k]*Gamma[23/5 + k]*Gamma[47/10 + k]*Gamma[49/10 + k]*
  Gamma[51/10 + k]*Gamma[53/10 + k]*Gamma[28/5 + k] //. rule
```

[image: Simplification]

***Update***

If you have some formula that generates the above examples (as I certainly wouldn't want to type each term one at a time), then you should give that formula in your question.  That might make it possible to use the Gauss Multiplication Theorem (as suggested by @Lucas) and the duplication formula to simplify things.  But once items are multiplied together the order of terms might change or not be so recognizable.

For example in the first equation you have

```
Gamma[1/2 + k]*Gamma[7/10 + k]*Gamma[9/10 + k]*Gamma[1 + k]^6*
  Gamma[11/10 + k]*Gamma[13/10 + k]*Gamma[3/2 + k]*Gamma[17/10 + k]....
```

Why would there be `Gamma[1 + k]^6` ?  None of the other terms are raised to a power.  Having such terms that mask the pattern won't make things easier.

Comment: Aren't all the gammas simplifiable via Gauss' multiplication theorem to something like $\Gamma(10x) / \Gamma(5x)$

Comment: @Lucas You should post an answer using that theorem.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure how to do it in generality, or I would have.

Comment: Specifically, how does one match a specific product of gammas

Comment: I've added an update to suggest that you describe how you get the products of gammas.  It looks like at least some little bit of simplification has already occurred which might mask any patterns necessary for substantial simplification.

Comment: Thanks very much. This should all be very helpful in trying to condense a large expression I have. There are also occurrences in them of terms like Gamma[1/10(17+10 k)], and I don't seem immediately able to put it in the form Gamma[17/10+k] to which to then apply Jim Baldwin's suggested rule.(I just saw JB's update--a nice point that I had also realized. I was planning to go back to the "raw" result [before my simplifications] and try the suggested rule. Thanks again--very helpful. I'll see how things work out (tomorrow) and may report back.

Comment: OK, now I've read JB's full update. Actually the basic problem is that I recently raised in the exchange http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/124342/find-rsolve-solution-reflecting-special-structure-of-differencerootfunction/124428#124428  What I'm trying to do now is to simplify the "second part" of the RSolve solution described there. This had a LeafCount > 20000 and dozens of included hypergeometric functions ranging form 7F6 to 13F12. Since FullSimplify clearly won't work here, I've taken the underlying formula for the hypergeometric functions and working with that.

Comment: I was about about of space in the just  submitted comment, so I'll continue here. I've mapped the hypergeometric functions to their underlying summation formulas, but ignore the actual summation for the moment. I'm happy to send the indicated "second part" if one wants--too large to include in the stack exchange, I assume. Also, I have at least one (larger) RSolve problem of a related nature "in the pipe" to be addressed. This all pertains to quantum-information-theoretic/random-matrix issues described by me (and Charles Dunkl) in the arXiv.