# What is the natural sequence of commands to apply RSolve to a DifferenceRoot[Function?

Tags: equation-solving, functions, difference-equations

I am generating some `DifferenceRoot[Function`s, but to apply `RSolve` to them, I'm just doing some cutting and pasting from the result. I assume there must be a more fluid/natural way to handle this.

Well, to use an example from the `DifferenceRoot` help page

```
PellNumber = 
DifferenceRoot[
Function[{y, n}, {-y[n] - 2 y[1 + n] + y[2 + n] == 0, y[0] == 0, 
 y[1] == 1}]];
```

I then entered

```
RSolve[PellNumber[[1]][[2]], \[FormalY][\[FormalN]], \[FormalN]]
```

which yielded

```
{{\[FormalY][\[FormalN]] -> -(((1 - Sqrt[2])^\[FormalN] - (1 + Sqrt[
   2])^\[FormalN])/(2 Sqrt[2]))}}
```

I considered posting this as an answer to the earlier version of the question (that is, the first paragraph), but the site is rather intimidating if one tries to do so - and I guess there might be an even more direct approach.

Comment: Please see my [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/123660/1063) to an earlier question of yours.

Comment: Thanks, bbgodfrey for the earlier reference. It still isn't quite clear to me how if one generates a DifferenceRoot[Function,  one can in the next command  "feed" the result into RSolve. (I'm not very conversant with this First[Head[f]][y, n] sequence/usage.)

Comment: OK--it seems that I can employ RSolve[First[Head[f]][y, n], y, n][[1, 1]], following the bbgodrey code.